# visual basic 2012 how to change icon

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to change icons while a program is running (multiple times, depending on what is happening). How do I do this:

I have tried "me.icon = image("icon location")" but get errors with converting images to icons.

Comment: So the real question is *"how to convert an image to an icon"* wouldn't you say?

Comment: Not necessarily, I was trying to find any method that could allow me to change icons with code (ie. while the program is running in reaction to events), either a different method (like Pragnesh provided), or the finished version of the method would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code will help you

```
Dim img As New System.Drawing.Icon("path to file")
Me.Icon = img
```